# Shorten a regex for HH:MM:SS

Tags: regex

is there a way to shorten the following to find a time in the format HH:MM:SS?

```
'^[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9]$'
```

Comment: Presumably HH should be restricted to < 24?

Comment: That's fine for this one. It has to do with run time of media.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anything, it ought to be longer, since `69:69:69` does not make sense as a time.

```
([01]\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d|60):([0-5]\d|60)
allow 00-23     00-59 and 60 00-59 and 60
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                60 is useful for supporting leap seconds
```

If you really want your example, but shorter, you can do it:

```
[0-6]\d(:[0-6]\d){2}
     ~~          ~~~
      |          exactly two repetitions of preceding () block
      Matches digits in many regex implementations
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't need to do validation of the values, but just find things that look like times, how about just:

```
\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}
```

*If you are searching through text to find values you don't really want to anchor at `^` and `$` unless your regex flavor has those matching at the beginning and end of line, and your source data has these on their own lines.*

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "you don't really want to anchor at ^ and $ unless your regex flavor has those matching at the beginning and end of line"?

Comment: If you have the text `"Starting at 11:22:33"` and you use a regex `/^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/` to test or scan it, the result will be "no match". If you have the text: `"Times:\n11:22:33\n44:55:66\nOK"` and you use that same regex to scan for matches in JavaScript, you will get no matches; the same regex in Ruby will return two matches, however, because in Ruby `^` means "start of line", not "start of string" (and `$` is "end of line", not "end of string").